# Setup program needs framework 4.0 - But it's already installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, installation

I created a service which I now want to install to test. When running the setup program it prompts me to download and install .net fw 4.0, but I already have it installed. I did try to just install the file that I get pointed to (4.0 cliet), but not only does it still not work, it causes vs2010 to throw an unknown error and can't open.

I've now uninstalled everything and started afresh with VS2010, framework 4.0 and win 7 but it still prompts me to install fw 4.0 when I try to run the setup. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanx in advance
Willem

Comment: What install creation application are you using?

Comment: You are going to have to give up on the free beta and RC editions for VS2010.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas:

1. I assume you have rebooted your machine; if not, do this and try again.
2. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00318785.aspx) about verifying your .NET 4.0 installation.
3. Using IE, go to http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ and ensure that .NET 4.0 is shown.
4. In VS 2010, write a small console app that outputs `Environment.Version.ToString()`. This is the .NET CLR version. Run this app from outside VS 2010, and ensure it works as expected.
5. At this point the problem is most likely with the installer used to create the service. Please add more information about it.

Comment: I'm having this problem with a Deployment Project in VS2019. It's the old installer that makes a Setup.exe and the .msi . If I run the MSI it installs fine. If I run Setup.exe it always wants to install Framework 4.8 despite it being installed.