# Setup requires .NET 4.0 - System already has .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I created a service which I now want to install to test, I created a setup program from the templates in Visual Studio 2010. When running the setup program it prompts me to download and install .NET 4.0, but I already have it installed. I did try to just install the file that I get pointed to (4.0 client), but not only does it still not work, it causes VS2010 to throw an unknown error and can't open.

I've now uninstalled everything (including VS2010 beta) and started afresh with VS2010 ultimate trial full version, .NET Framework 4.0 and Windows 7 but it still prompts me to install .NET 4.0 when I try to run the setup. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this error happen on your development machine, or another computer which has .NET 4 installed?

Comment: Ive only tested it on my development machine as I don't have immediate access to another.

Comment: Just tested the same thing created firstly with the new version and it works fine. Must be a bug in the beta version.
Thanx anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749757/setup-program-needs-framework-4-0-but-its-already-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Must have been a bug in the beta version of VS2010.