# how to install/reinstall .net 4.0 on windows 8

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am suffering from this problem

[Script not served by static file handler on IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762287/script-not-served-by-static-file-handler-on-iis7-5)

but I cannot use any of the suggestions since I am on windows 8. aspnet_regiis tells me it will not run on windows 8 and that I should use the add/remove windows features control panel, but that control panel only lists .net 3.5 and 4.5, not 4.0

I have tried downloading .net 4.0 but it says it is already installed. So I am a bit stuck. if it is installed, I can't see any way to remove it, and if it isn't installed, I can't find any way to install it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749757/setup-program-needs-framework-4-0-but-its-already-installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is just an in-place upgrade from .NET 4.0. If you just uninstall 4.5 and reinstall it, it should do the job

Comment: Thanks - it explicitly said that 3.5 includes 2.0 but it didn't say anywhere that 4.5 includes 4.0 so I assumed it didn't. Anyway if anyone else is having this problem, note that you have to remove and add .Net not just from the top level ".Net 4.5" section in the control panel, but also expand under "Internet Information Services\World Wide Web Services\Application Development Features" and remove/re-add it in there as well. Now I'm up and running again :)